# Wordpress Could not copy file. /var/www/wp-content/upgrade/attitude.tmp/attitude/images/my-space@2x.png

Tags: wordpress, unix

This problem occurs when I try to install any themes inside my wordpress admin console.
I have tried change the owner of the /var/www directories (with `chown -R <username> /var/www`) I have also setup permission 755 for the directory. I realize the problem is due to  the file's permission in the upgrade directory. The file has permission `-rw-r--r--` (this directory and files inside are supposed to be created by the FTP user I supplied when installing the theme)

Comment: I think there is need of 777 permission ? please give it a try ?

Comment: Actually I tried that but no luck.

Comment: strange @ caracter in url. Could this be some IIS - Unix ressource link issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have selinux installed?
You can check by going to the ssh window and type `# sestatus`

It should show you

```
SELinux status: enabled/disabled


SeLinuxfs mount: /selinux


Current mode: enforce/permissive

Mode from config file: enforce

Policy Version: XX

Policy from config file: targeted
```

if it's on 'enforce', you can temporarily change it to permissive to see if that's your issue but using

```
# setenforce 0

# getenforce // Should return permissive
```

Try to upload then. If it works you need to add that directory to tell selinux to allow httpd to write there.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t DIRECTORY/PATH/THAT/YOU/WANT/TO/WRITE/TO/
```

Hope this helps